# How to get values for a Drop Down menu based on the selection of another Drop Down

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to populate a drop down list but based on the selection of another drop down (both values must be populated from Database).

I have a carrier list, which I successfully managed to populate it from the Database. Now, I want to populate the Plan drop down list based on the Carrier selected by sending its ID.

**HTML (Both Drop Down)**

```
<!--ENTER CARRIER-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="carrier">Carrier:</label>
                    <select id="drpCarrier" class="form-control" name="carrierName" required onchange="getPlan(this.value);">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Carrier</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <!--ENTER PLAN-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="plan">Plan:</label>
                    <select id="drpPlans" class="form-control" name="PlanName" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Plan</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

The script for Carrier, values are returned from controller. (Controller code attached below).

This is the ajax which populated the Carrier drop down.

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "@Url.Action("getCarrierList", "SimInventory")",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.type == "Success") {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    var item = response.data[i];
                    var planOption; planOption += "<option value=" + item.ID + ">" + item.Name + "</option>";
                }
                document.getElementById("drpCarrier").innerHTML = planOption;
            }
            else{
                if(response.type == "Error")
                    notifyMe(response.message, "Warning");
            }$('#loading_spinner').hide();
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
        $('#loading_spinner').hide();
    }
});
```

This is the script for populating the plans, which it is supposed to but unfortunately not working.

```
function getPlan(value){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: value,
            url: "@Url.Action("getPlanList", "SimInventory")",
            success: function (response) {
            if (response.type == "Success") {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
            else
                if (response.type == "Error") {
                    notifyMe(response.message, "Warning");
                }
            $('#loading_spinner').hide();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            $('#loading_spinner').hide();
        }
    });
    }
```

The controller

```
public JsonResult getCarrierList()
    {
        try
        {
            CarrierBLL carrier = new CarrierBLL();
            var carrierlist = carrier.GetAllCarriers();

            return Json(new { type = "Success", data = carrierlist }); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            if(ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                message += ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
            _Common.Log(message, "SimInventory", "getCarrierList");
            return Json(new { type = "Error", message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Now my question is, how do I achieve this functionality. Once the user selects any of the carrier then the plan should be available for the selected carrier only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest you study the code in this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery on change instead of getPlan() function,

And please remove the onchange event in your select box.

```
<select id="drpCarrier" class="form-control" name="carrierName" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Carrier</option>
</select>


$('#drpCarrier').on('change', function() {
var value = $('#drpCarrier :selected').text();
  $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: value,
            url: "@Url.Action("getPlanList", "SimInventory")",
            success: function (response) {
            if (response.type == "Success") {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
            else
                if (response.type == "Error") {
                    notifyMe(response.message, "Warning");
                }
            $('#loading_spinner').hide();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            $('#loading_spinner').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @AbdullahBasheer Ok Fine. Please accept the answer if it helpful to you.

Comment: Yes it was very helpful. Thanks again